# Finding arithmetic mean using geometric mean information

Tags: inequality, average, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The product of two integers is $10$

**Compare :**

Quantity A :  The arithmetic mean of the integers
Quantity B :  $3$

**Options:**

A) Quantity A > Quantity B

B) Quantity A < Quantity B

C) Quantity A = Quantity B

D) Cannot be determined

---

My solution:

Ive compared it using  the relation  **AM >= GM**
Suppose the numbers be a and b

**AM >= GM**

$\frac{a+b}{2}  \ge  \sqrt{ab}$

$\frac{a+b}{2}  \ge  \sqrt{10}$

$\frac{a+b}{2}  \ge  3.162$

Hence,   Option A) Quantity A > Quantity B

---

Is this solution correct as the answer to this question is given as  option D) Cannot be determined

Comment: $a$ and $b$ can be possibly negative so your AM-GM will not be valid in that scenario. For example, if $a=-5,b=-2$, then AM$=-3.5$

Comment: Okay, so we cannot apply  AM-GM for negative terms.

Comment: with some values it still wouldn't work to extract restricted to positives. because $2\cdot 5\cdot 5= 2\cdot 25 = 10\cdot 5$ the geometric mean of both  of the latter products is $\sqrt{50}$ the the arithmetic means, are 13.5 and 7.5 so there is no function possible between geometric means and a distinct arithmetic mean in every case.

Comment: Yes, the terms needs to be fixed. Given a list of terms we can apply AM-GM inequality (except for negative terms), but not on the combinations of terms/ the possible cases for the terms involved. Discerned it.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Suppose $x>0$ and compare $$f (x)=x+\frac {10}{x} $$
with $6$.

$$f'(x)=\frac {x^2-10}{x^2}$$

the minimum is $f(\sqrt {10})=2\sqrt {10}>6$
hence $A>B $.

If $x <0$ then $f (x)<0 <6$.

Comment: @OP she is comparing 1/2 (x + 10/x) to 3 (AM-GM), which is simplified as such +1